How to restrict data from logged in user in Django
I want to restrict the index page for logged in user. Instead of that I want to show them another index.
I have a function based view file. People without an account can view the page or logged out but those who logged in can not view the index.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Without further information from you, I'd suggest trying out this in your views:
if request.user.is_authenticated:
  # restricted index
else:
  # normal index

or this within your template:
{% if user.is_autheticated %}
restricted index
{% else %}
unrestricted index
{% endif %}

You could also use a decorator if you'd only mean to lock the page for some group, but if I understood correctly you want to have different content on the same page for different users.
